# If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, show that $gN(H)g^{-1}=N(gHg^{-1})$ for any $g\in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Where $N(H)$ is the normalizer of $G$. That is, $N(H)=\{g\in G:gHg^{-1}=H\}$.

So far I have that $x\in  gN(H)g^{-1} \iff x\in N(H)$ by the normalcy of $N(H)$, but I'm unsure of how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normaliser is **not** in general a normal subgroup of $G$. It is the largest subgroup of $G$ in which $H$ is normal. For example, the normaliser of a non-trivial subgroup of any simple group $G$ (e.g. $A_5$) cannot be a normal subgroup of $G$.

Rather, we have 
$$
x\in gN(H) g^{-1} \iff g^{-1}xg \in N(H) \iff (g^{-1}xg) H(g^{-1}x^{-1}g) = H \iff x(gHg^{-1})x^{-1} = gHg^{-1} 
$$